# как реализовать отправку сообщения от сервера

Tags: c++, grpc

Использую С++ и  gRPC.  С отправкой сообщений от клиента на сервер все понятно. А что если требуется от сервера отправить сообщение клиенту - как это можно реализовать?
в документации примеры только отправки ответов на запросы от клиента.

Comment: А такой сценарий вроде не поддерживается. В любом случае сначала клиентъ должен отправить какой-то запрос, а затем уже сервер может отправлять ему ответы.

Comment: клиент можно время от времени отправлять специальные "пинг" запросы. А сервер ему пришлет либо просто "понг" с признаком "есть ли новые сообщения" или прям и сами сообщения. Естественно, если слать сильно часто - уложим сервер, слать слишком медленно - будет лаг. Приходится балансировать или искать дополнительный канал обмена сообщенийми (xmpp к примеру)